# Consuming google_services status page JSONP in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, jsonp

I'm looking to get service status of all response code and get how many services are up and running fine like,

If 10 services are there 9 service are UP and one down.Result should be in form of

```
{
  9/10 working,
  dash service DOWN
}
```

Or any another form to get status
I'm trying to retrieve data from

> https://www.google.com/appsstatus/json/en

I don't know how to process JSONP from appscript

I have tried using

```
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/appsstatus/json/en' + uri, options).getContentText();
    
 function dashboard.jsonp(data){

       return data;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched for any resources related to JSONP on Apps Script and found [Serving JSONP in web pages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages). However, the link samples are quite limited.

**Recommendation:**

With that being said, I have tried scraping the JSONP from https://www.google.com/appsstatus/json/en and you may check this code below as reference:

```
/**
 * @Custom code google_services status page JSONP
 */

function checkServices(){ //Main function to run in the Apps Script editor
  Logger.log("Total number of down services: "+countDownServices(getStatusOfServices()).length);
  Logger.log("Total services:" + countAllServices());
  Logger.log(countAllServices() - countDownServices(getStatusOfServices()).length +"/"+countAllServices()+" Working\nDown Service(s)\n"+countDownServices(getStatusOfServices()));

}

function parseDashboardJSONP(){ //Get the JSON values from JSONP to be easily parsed in the other functions
  var jsonData = "https://www.google.com/appsstatus/json/en"
  var jsonFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(jsonData).getContentText();
  var text = jsonFile.replace("dashboard.jsonp(","");
  return text.replace(");","");
}

function getServicesData(){ //Get all current services and their IDs from the JSONP link
  var containerData = [];
  var parsethedata = JSON.parse(parseDashboardJSONP()); //Parse the JSON value
  try{
      for(var x = 0; x=>0; x++){
      var getServiceName = parsethedata.services[x].name; //Parse the service names from the JSON values
      var getServiceID = parsethedata.services[x].id; //Parse the service id from the JSON values
      containerData[getServiceID] = getServiceName; //Put all parse data into an array
      }
  }catch(e){
    //Logger.log("End of the line");
  }
  return containerData;
}

function getStatusOfServices(){ //Get all service names that were down
  var containerStatus = [];
  var parsethedata = JSON.parse(parseDashboardJSONP()); //Parse the JSON value
  try{
    for(var x = 0; x=>0; x++){
      var getID = parsethedata.messages[x].service; //Get the service ID from the "messages" node of the JSON value
      containerStatus[x] = getServicesData()[getID]; //Get the name of the service from "services" node that matches with the service ID from "messages" node
    }
  }catch(e){
    //Logger.log("End of the line");
  }
  return containerStatus;
}

function countAllServices(){ //Count all services from the "services" node of the JSON data
  var count = 0;
  for(var x=0; x<getServicesData().length;x++){
    if(getServicesData()[x]!=null){
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

function countDownServices(array) { //Remove the duplicate services that are on the "messages" node of the JSON data and count all of the down services unique names
  var outArray = [];
  array.sort(lowerCase);
  function lowerCase(a,b){
    return a.toLowerCase()>b.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;// sort function that does not "see" letter case
  }
  outArray.push(array[0]);
  for(var n in array){
    if(outArray[outArray.length-1].toLowerCase()!=array[n].toLowerCase()){
      outArray.push(array[n]);
    }
  }
  return outArray;
}
```

After running the code above, this will be the result on the Execution Logs:

[image]

Here's the overview of the formatted JSON data from the code `parseDashboardJSONP()` is using. I've used [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/):

[image]

When some of the nodes are expanded:
[image]

Comment: Counting old event is false, I'm only looking current status on services, anyway code is working fine I have re-modified for my requirement, good work